# Certain Range of Date in each Month

Tags: date, google-bigquery, range

I'd like to have a range of day 20th - 25th in each month in BigQuery but i dont know what syntax should i use. For ex:
Jan 20 - 25
Feb 20 - 25
and so on

I only can think of creating a CTE for every month then union all those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below query.

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL day - 1 DAY) date_range,
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2022-03-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month,
       UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(20, 25)) day;
```

###### Query results

[image]

Below seem to be more simple than my original answer and you could adjust date range by specifying condition on WHERE clause.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) date_range
 WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_range) BETWEEN 21 AND 25
```

For the usecase that you commented,

> WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_range) >= 21 OR EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_range) = 1

Comment: what if i want to have a range day 21(current month ) - 1(the next month), how the unnest syntax will be

Comment: @farinirzani, kindly check my updated answer. hope it helps.